# Count all records of table ignoring filters

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a power bi report which contains a table. This table displays and sql table content.

There are several slicers on the reports which apply a filter on the table.

What i want to do is to display the total number of records, ignoring filters.

I have tried a DAX formula with COUNT: but COUNT takes care of filter. How can i ignore them ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
Calculate(Countrows([tablename],
    All([tablename]) )
```

Answer (score 1):

or this

```
Calculate(Count('tablename'[Id]), FILTER(All('tablename'),'tablename'[Title]<>""))
```